# Excel - Selecting Rows where Multiple Columns ==

Tags: excel

So I have an excel sheet that basically lists a bunch of inventory, with rows of headings like "ID Number" "Location" "Type"

I'm wondering, how can I get or sort by, only the data in the Location and Type columns?

For example, I want to find only rows with type PRINTER and location WEST, is there a way to use a query-like command?- something like

```
*WHERE type = printer && location = WEST*
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

A pivot table allows you to filter and display just those categories.

You could get a more complicated, array formula solution, that will return all matches based on the criteria you select. It's an implementation of an index match using array formulas, matching the criteria you choose. The only advantage this offers is not having to refresh the pivot tables.

[This sample should give you an idea.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oK13e.jpg)
In order for it to work:

- Select an array where you want it to act
- Input the formula into the first cell
- Confirm it with Ctrl+Shift+Enter

The last part ("ROW() - 3"): as a rule of thumb, do it as

```
ROW() - ( [current row] - 1 )
```

Otherwise it will not work properly.

See [this excellent post](http://chandoo.org/wp/2014/12/09/multiple-occurrences-lookup-and-extraction/) for details on how to implement it and some variations.

You never mentioned VBA, so I'll refrain from over-complicating things with it.

Edit(1): I forgot to mention, the number returned by the formula is the *matching row*, so in order to return a value just wrap it with

```
INDEX( [column_you_want] , <formula> )
```

and add an IFERROR to remove the #NUMS